# How to bind MenuItem.Header to Window/UserControl dependency property?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I`m wondering how can I bind MenuItem.Header to the parent Window/UserControl dependency property? Here is a simple example:

**Window1.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" x:Name="self">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=MenuText, ElementName=self}" />
            </ContextMenu>
        </Grid.ContextMenu>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=MenuText, ElementName=self}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window1.xaml.cs**:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MenuTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "MenuText", typeof (string), typeof (Window1), new PropertyMetadata("Item 1"));

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MenuText {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(MenuTextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(MenuTextProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In my case, textblock displays "Item 1", and context menu displays empty item. What I`m doing wrong? It seems for me, that I faced serious misunderstaning of WPF databinding principles.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should see this in the Output window of Visual Studio:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot
>   find source for binding with reference
>   'ElementName=self'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=MenuText;
>   DataItem=null; target element is
>   'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'Header' (type 'Object')

That is because the ContextMenu is disconnected from the VisualTree, you need to do this Binding differently.

One way is via `ContextMenu.PlacementTarget` (which should be the Grid), you could use its DataContext to establish a binding, e.g.:

```
<MenuItem Header="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.MenuText}"/>
```

or set up the DataContext in the ContextMenu itself:

```
<ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext}">
    <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=MenuText}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

If this is not an option (because the DataContext of the Grid cannot be the Window/UserControl) you can try to pass the reference to the Window/UserControl through the `Tag` of your Grid for example.

```
<Grid ...
      Tag="{x:Reference self}">
    <Grid.ContextMenu>
        <!-- The DataContext is now bound to PlacementTarget.Tag -->
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=PlacementTarget.Tag}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Path=MenuText}"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    ...
```

---

As a side-note: Because of this behavior i tend to define a helper-style in `App.xaml` to make all ContextMenus "pseudo-inherit" the DataContext from their parent:

```
    <!-- Context Menu Helper -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContextMenu}">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
    </Style>
```

Comment: Could you please clarify how to pass the reference to the Window/UserControl through the Tag? If I use Tag="{x:Reference self}" syntax, I get compilation error **"The tag 'Reference' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'.** I use VS2008 and .NET framework 3.5.

Comment: Only exists in .NET 4, you should be able to use a Binding instead, something like `Tag="{Binding ElementName=self}"`

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to H.B.'s solution is this attached behavior: [ContextMenuServiceExtensions.DataContext Attached Property](http://thrash505.wordpress.com/2011/04/20/contextmenuserviceextensions-datacontext-attached-property/)